# Expression Engine - Why is a template in the main directory 404?

Tags: expressionengine

I have been using .htaccess rules to hide the index page of EE sites for years now and this generally allows me to create a template within the site template group that will display without having to include the name of the site template group in the URL. Like this:

http://mysite.com/template_name

However, I am working on a site where I tried this and I keep getting a 404 error.

Here is the .htaccess code I am using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Here is the actual path: http://corecubed.com/main/landing-page
This is what it should be displaying as: http://corecubed.com/landing-page

(Note: this page is for mobile devices and displays quite large on a regular web page.)

Question is, why won't it display properly without including the name of the site template group and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like **Strict URLs** are enabled under your Global Template Preferences. Try toggling that setting off.